# Dictionary with a string mapped to function

Tags: c#

I'm relatively new to C#. I was working on a few console app projects that rely on user input and fire off different functions depending on their input.

I thought that it might be simpler and a bit more flexible to map the possible inputs to a function in a dictionary.

I was told this may be a bad design choice, but wasn't given a clear explanation why.

```
class Request<T> : IRequest<T>
{
    string Route { get; set; }
    T Body { get; set; }
}

class Response<T> : IResponse<T>
{
    string Route { get; set; }
    T Body { get; set; }
}


class Router : IRoutable
{
    Dictionary<string, Func<IRequest<T>, IResponse<T>> Routes { get; set; }
}
```

Can this make my design worse / more fragile? If so, why?

Comment: "I was told this may be a bad design choice" by who? Based on what? What would they have done instead? Why? I don't see anything bad here.

Comment: looks fine to me. Common thing for state machines etc.

Comment: Why are you asking us for an explanation of someone's opinion rather than the person who told you said opinion?

Comment: The design flaw I'd immediately notice here is *why are all these properties read-write*? It seems crazy to me that anyone in the world can take an existing request and *change its body*.  That sounds like a security nightmare. Similarly, anyone can change not just the contents of the dictionary, which is already bad, but *the dictionary itself*.

Comment: Is the set of strings finite and known at compile time, or dynamic and configurable at runtime?

Comment: The strings would be defined in the constructor of a whatever class this construct is injected into. It's access would be protected / private (depending on the need). I'd insert methods of it's containing class, along with a string to define the user input that maps to the function.

Comment: So the set of strings is finite. It's not meant to be adjusted or modified after run time.

Comment: I assume that the string in the request/response route properties is also the string used as the dictionary key? (Hint: **What did the fact that I had to ask the question tell you about your design?**)

Answer (score 3):

> I was told this may be a bad design choice, but wasn't given a clear explanation why.

You should ask that person for clarification.

> Can this make my design worse / more fragile? If so, why?

(I assume that your interfaces, which you have not shown, have the same surface area as the classes which implement them. If that's not the case, then you've omitted key details from your question and should update the question.)

Yes, absolutely.  Your design allows anyone to change any aspect of the system at any time for any reason! That's a security nightmare.

Also, it exposes what ought to be an implementation detail in the interface. Suppose someone wanted to use a concurrent dictionary? Or an immutable lookup?  Nope, they cannot; they are *required* to use a dictionary in your interface.

Let's step back. What are the basic parts?

- A route is represented by a string
- A request has a body and a route
- A response has a body and a route
- A server takes a request and returns a response
- A router takes a route and returns a server.

So let's write those.

```
interface IRoute
{
  string Route { get; }
}
interface IRequest<T>
{
  IRoute Route { get; }
  T Request { get; }
}
interface IResponse<T>
{
  IRoute Route { get; }
  T Response { get; }
}
interface IServer
{
  IResponse<T> Process<T>(IRequest<T> request);
}
interface IRouter
{
  IServer GetServer(IRoute route);
}
```

Remember, **interfaces represent the bare minimum contract you need to expose to their clients**.  Is there any reason why you need to know that IRouter is implemented with a Dictionary?  No. Then **don't expose that**. A router takes a route and gives you a server, end of story. Let the implementer decide whether they want to use a dictionary or not.

Is any possible string a route? Can any route be used as a string?  If not, then don't represent routes as strings in the interface. Is it ever possible that someone mistakes a string expression that does not represent a route for one that does?  Make the type system catch that bug! **Make a type representing routes.**

Similarly, don't let anyone write anything that they don't have business writing. Every property should be read-only in the interface unless it is a by-design feature of the type that the property be mutable by anyone.

Another question is: why interfaces at all? Are you going to have three or more implementations of each?  If not, consider making them sealed classes or structs instead, preferably immutable types.